# I am trying to solve the Euler.net(10) to sum the prime numbers less than 2 million.The program keeps going on and on and on

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i,c=0 ,flag, n,limit;
    cout << "enter a limit\n";
    cin >> limit;
    for (i = 2; i < limit;i++)
    {
        flag = 0;
      for (n = 2; n <= i - 1; n++)
          if (i%n == 0)
            flag = 1;
      if (flag == 0)
              c = c + i;
    }
    cout << c << "\n";
    getchar(); getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The program keeps running for the value 2 million while it works in other cases. Is the above algorithm correct?

Comment: As 2 million is too big value and it will check each value with its lower values, which need lots of time. You can try `n < sqrt(i);` at the place of `n <= i - 1;`. it will reduce number of iterations. Also use `break;` after `flag=1;`

Comment: @Himanshu don't do sqrt on every iteration please....

Comment: @NoIdeaForName take an integer variable and save its value then, it will be fine. Yaa just like in your answer.

Comment: @Himanshu that's what i meant... like in my answer....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm is correct but inefficient. Some optimization might help but it will still take too long. One solution is to allocate a `char[2000000]` and find all primes by using ["Sieve of Eratosthenes"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

```
long long int i, c = 0, limit;
cout << "enter a limit\n";
cin >> limit;
char *p = new char[limit]();

for (i = 2; i < limit; i++)
{
    // if i is prime
    if (!p[i]) {
        for (int j = i; j < limit; j += i)
        {
            p[j] = 1;
        }
        c += i;
    }
}
cout << c << "\n";
getchar(); getchar();
return 0;
```

Comment: thanks man! That's pretty fast. I have recently started programming and I am trying to come up with algorithms based on the definition and I have a very little knowledge of optimization.

Comment: can you plz elaborate the step char *p=new char[limit](); ? I am unable to comprehend how is this Sieve of Eratosthenes.

Answer (score 0):

the above algorithm will work as it does what it asked to do ( check if `i` is divided by `n` with no leftover)

however you can improve it by breaking when you find a divider and not running pass the square root of i
include

```
#include <math.h>
```

and in the loop

```
int iSqr = sqrt(i);
for (n = 2; n <= iSqr ; n++)
{
    if (i%n == 0){
       flag = 1;
       break;
    }
}
```

Comment: what difference does n<=iSqr make? Why to go only upto less than the square-root?

Comment: @user4275686 hii there, first of all, we go up until square-root, not less then that, and if a number isn't a prime number, then a divider will be found for him in this range

Comment: but don't you think there will be primes after the square root? I am a little dizzy here.Will you elaborate please.The output I am getting is correct as well as effective but how is the code working on square root?

Comment: i can't find a good reference for that, so i leave i for you. but think about it: for every divider above the square root (we'll call it x) there need to be a second divider(we call it y) so n/x=y. ok so far? so if x is above square root then y must be below (or x*y > n). i truly hope you will get that, it's not simple to understand, but it is true